# find value of unknown angle

Tags: geometry

let us consider following problem

[image]

we should find value of $x$,i have redrawn this figure using paint

[image]

it  seams that value  $x$ should be equal to $75+60=135$,but in answers list it is not so,so i have calculate adjacent angles of  each angle and got two angle one is $180-75=105$  and second is $120$,so in total it should be  360,so  angle $x$ is $360-105-50-120=85$,answer coincide,but why  first method does not work?

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

The figure containing in its interior $\,x\,$ and $\,50^\circ\;$ is a convex quadrilateral and thus the sum of its angles is $\,360^\circ\;$

Also, the complementary angle of an angle $\;\alpha\;$ is $\;180^\circ-\alpha\;$ ...

I think the mistake in the first method is that you're trying to apply the exterior angle *of a triangle* theorem to a quadrilateral...

Comment: i  saw such kind of method in baron's book and remember this

Comment: if for example angle $50$ is not given ,then we can't determine yes  $x$

Answer (score 0):

x by direct method is not $75^ \circ + 60^ \circ$ . But it is $75^ \circ +60^ \circ -50^ \circ = 85^ \circ $

You have to consider all angles of quadrilateral. You left $50 ^ \circ$ . Its not possible to find one angle in an irregular polygon when all others are not given.

one unknown angle = (n-2)*180 - remaining interior angles

or

one unknown angle = sum of (n-2) exterior angles given - remaining interior angles

n-2 exterior angles because the n-2 180 degrees is cancelled by the 180 coming from interior angle = 180 -exterior

refer : [interior and exterior angle](http://www.mathopenref.com/polygonanglerelation.html)

Comment: With regard to the last statement: If the (perhaps irregular) quadrilateral was cyclic and you knew it in advance, then you would only need to know the $50^\circ$ angle to calculate $x$.

Comment: In this case it is not cyclic

Comment: You were making a general remark which does not apply to all cases.

Comment: I have updated my answer to substantiate my point why OP has said he has seen a formula like that

Comment: I think Harish's answer was clear enough. It would be quite an inconvenience to have to say "in general" at the end of sentences like that all the time. Like when someone says "rings are not groups", it is not *too wrong* (such a human phrase) if you understand the intention of the speaker.